# debootstrap: unknown user 'root' in state override file

Tags: linux, debian, system-installation

I muffed up my graphics card driver and/or xconfig files and decided to just reinstall Debian Linux (squeeze 6.0.6) last night. Part way through installing the base system, it failed. Sorry, I didn't write down the exact error message at that point. The last line on console 4 was

> debootstrap: unknown user 'root' in state override file

What do I need to do to get the installation to complete successfully? Or what resources should I look out to figure it out?

Doing some research, I found [this bug report ticket](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=617235) which looks like a very similar issue. I am installing from a CD using the graphical installer and followed all the steps up to installing the base system. I configured the mount points for my HDD partitions as follows:

> sda1 - /
>   sda5 - /usr
>   sda6 - /var
>   sda7 - swap
>   sda8 - /tmp
>   sda9 - /home

These are the partitions from my original installation. I only formatted sda1 during the installation.

I know the information I have available is quite sparse. I'm posting this from another  computer. When I have some more time, I'll get some more info from my machine. What other data do I need to diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by formatting *all* partitions *except* sda9 (/home). This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and it turned out it was `/etc/passwd` that was corrupt. Fixed that and it works again.